# counting refractive index of a plano convex lens

Tags: optics

suppose that, there is a plano convex lens and its thickness is 5.00cm. If you watch it straight from the convex side, it seems that its of 4.4 cm. What is the refractive index of this lens?

Answer (score 2):

Refraction occurs because of the slowing of light in a medium. So the ratio between the actual thickness and perceived thickness is directly related to the ratio of refractive index between that of the lens material and that of air.